# Removing parameter $t$ from $z$-axis

Tags: parametric

How do I remove the parameter $t$ from the $z$-function in the following:
$$\begin{align}x&=a\cos{t}-a\\
y&=a\sin{t}\\
z&=nt\end{align}$$
(where $n,a$ are arbitrary coefficients)
So far I have:
$$\begin{align}
x&=(a^2-y^2)^{0.5} - a\\
y&=(a^2 -(x+a))^{0.5}\end{align}$$
(though I haven't used $a^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$, which I am thinking that I should replace $a$ with it.)
But $z$ has me confused on how to eliminate $t$.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$\cos ^2{t}-\sin^2{t}=\cos{2t}=\dfrac{y^2-(x-a)^2}{a^2} \implies t=\dfrac{1}{2}(\arccos{\dfrac{y^2-(x-a)^2}{a^2}}+2k\pi)\implies z=\dfrac{n}{2}(\arccos{\dfrac{y^2-(x-a)^2}{a^2}}+2k\pi)$

Answer (score 0):

The first two equations give you
$$
\cos t = \frac{x+a}{a} \quad ; \quad \sin t = \frac{y}{a}
$$
Dividing the second by the first gives
$$
\tan t = \frac{\sin t}{\cos t} = \frac{y}{x+a}
$$
and so 
$$
t = \arctan\frac{y}{x+a} + 2k\pi
$$
for some integer $k$. Substituting this in the equation for $z$ gives
$$
z = n \arctan\frac{y}{x+a} + 2k\pi
$$
The equations represent a helix, if you're interested.